# Putting elements in an array?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a question. I'll post the HTML first, I know you shouldn't use tables for designing and stuff like that. But it's for learning purposes only.

```
<table id="placeholder">
<tr>
    <td><img src="img/1.jpg"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/2.jpg"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/3.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="img/4.jpg"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/5.jpg"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/6.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="img/7.jpg"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/8.jpg"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/9.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="img/10.jpg"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/11.jpg"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/12.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><img src="img/10.jpg"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/11.jpg"/></td>
    <td><img src="img/12.jpg"/></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Is it possible to put all the IMG's in an array?
That way I can easily fadeOut the images I want.
Let say I want to get rid of the 5th images, I can just do something like:
        `images[4].fadeOut("slow");`
Or something like that.
Is it possible to do this? Or is there a better way to do this?
I've already tried `var images = $('td > img');` but that didn't work (or i'm doing something wrong). I'm also searching the internet for ways to do it, but I haven't found anything yet that could help me. Hopefully you might? 

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can select all images with

```
var $images = $('#placeholder img');
```

If you now want to select a specific image, you can use [`.eq()` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/eq/):

```
$images.eq(4).fadeOut();
```

`$images[4]` works too, but it does **not** return a jQuery object, but the corresponding DOM element. Hence you cannot call `fadeOut` on it directly.

---

Without jQuery, you can get all the images with [`getElementsByTagName` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.getElementsByTagName):

```
var images = document.getElementById('placeholder').getElementsByTagName('img');
```

This gives you an array (actually a `NodeList`) of DOM elements  and again you cannot directly call the jQuery method `fadeOut` on them.

Comment: Thanks man! You really helped me out! I was searching for this at least for 2 hours! Thanks for the fast reply! It works great! Awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work, e.g.

```
var imgs = $("#placeholder td > img");
console.log (imgs[0]);
```

Your JS is probably loading before the page loads, so you need to put it in jQuery's document ready function:

```
$(function() {
    var imgs = $("#placeholder td > img");
    console.log (imgs[0]);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for youre answer and youre time! The answer above workes perfectly, so I'll probably use that one :) But thank you!

Comment: I don't know, I did have the jQuery document.ready function(). But well, it works now... So thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

It would be absolutely great if you *could* do this, but you can't. You'd like to be able to say `<td><img src=imagearray[5]><td>` but html and css don't allow it. You *can*, however, give each of the `<td>`s a class, store the images for each class as `background-image:`s, and fade those guys.

**EDIT:** oops, didn't see the jquery tag.

Answer (score 0):

`$('td > img')` returns not an array, but a jQuery object. So you can use it as so:

```
$('td > img').each(function(index, imageElement) {
    // Do logic based on the index or something else.
});
```